# Tomcat 6 finalize method

Tags: tomcat

Is there any way of executing code on Tomcat 6 when the application get stopped/unloaded ? (I am trying to deregister the MySQL driver by hand due to memory leaks problem).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Using a [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) is the standard procedure for this kind of stuff.

It has two methods that are useful: one fired during application initialization and one during application shutdown. These are, respectively,

```
void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
```

and

```
 void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
```

You'll want to use the second one for cleanup.

Implement the mentioned interface:

```
package com.myapp

public class AppListener implements ServletContextListener {

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
  {
     // Application shuts down. Put your cleanup code here.
  }

  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
  {
     // Application starts up.
  }

}
```

and register it in `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
     com.myapp.AppListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Register a ServletContextListener.